# When deploy a webapp to WebLogic12c encounters a JAXBException

Tags: weblogic

I try to deploy a application on WebLogic 12c(version:12.1.2.0.0), when staring up it encounters an Exception as blow:

```
Failed to create the JAXB binder; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: provider org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:
Exception Description: The java interface org.apache.camel.Endpoing can not be mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces. Multiple inheritence is not supported
 - with linked exception:
 [Exception [EclipseLink-50089] (Eclipse Persistence Service - 2.4.2.v2013-0514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The java interface org.apache.camel.Endpoing can not be mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces. Multiple inheritence is not supported
```

But it doesn't happen when deploy to WebLogic11g(version:10.3.3.0).
Is this caused by a jar conflict?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at the following threads:
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Spring-Camel-Context-initialization-error-in-weblogic-12c-td5733202.html

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Help-on-deploying-Camel-on-Weblogic-12c-Name-Collision-td5720837.html

After putting the jaxb.properties in my camel-spring-x.x.x.jar and redeploy, the problem has gone.